# Python: What is the typing signature for print?

Tags: python, typing

What is the typing signature for print or similar function which takes a variable number of arguments of any type, when defined as a Callable parameter?

Concretely, what is the  declaration of `output_function` here?

```
def f(x: str, output_function=print):
    output_function(x)
```

Update: clarified as a Callable parameter.

Comment: `*args: Any`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values)

> Arbitrary argument lists can as well be type annotated, so that the definition:
>
> ```
> def foo(*args: str, **kwds: int): ...
> ```
>
> is acceptable and it means that, e.g., all of the following represent function calls with valid types of arguments:
>
> ```
> foo('a', 'b', 'c')
> foo(x=1, y=2)
> foo('', z=0)
> ```

So `print` would be:

```
from typing import Any, IO
def print(*args: Any, sep: str = ' ', \
          end: str = '\n', file: IO = sys.stdout, \
          flush: bool = False) -> None:
```

I don't think you can apply this to a `Callable` though. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) for `typing`,

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types. `Callable[..., ReturnType]` (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments and returning `ReturnType`

Comment: Excellent! How about being declared as a Callable parameter?  I've updated the question to clarify that is what I was looking for.

Comment: mypy has no complaint with `x: Callable[..., None] = print`.

Comment: @MarkHarrison As far as I have seen, you can't explicitly specify that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable says _"There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types. `Callable[..., ReturnType]` (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments and returning `ReturnType`"_

Comment: Or use `typing.Protocol` with custom [`__call__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#callback-protocols).